# Pd Groupby would not group a column in pd

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a df which looks like this:

```
Visitor_ID  Form Name   Page Views  Downloads (event9)  Video Start (event1)    Form Open (event10) Form Success (event11)
0   1000012332_3700058682   NaN 1   0   0   0   0
1   1000012332_3700058682   NaN 0   0   0   0   0
2   1000025219_4231004519   NaN 1   0   0   0   0
3   1000025219_4231004519   NaN 1   0   0   0   0
4   1000036902_602553643    NaN 1   0   0   0   0
```

So I tried to do a groupby on Visitor_ID like this:

```
df = df.groupby(['Visitor_ID'])
```

Expected:

```
Visitor_ID  Form Name   Page Views  Downloads (event9)  Video Start (event1)    Form Open (event10) Form Success (event11)
0   1000012332_3700058682   NaN 1   0   0   0   0
1   1000025219_4231004519   NaN 2   0   0   0   0
2   1000036902_602553643    NaN 1   0   0   0   0
```

But I got

```
Visitor_ID  Form Name   Page Views  Downloads (event9)  Video Start (event1)    Form Open (event10) Form Success (event11)
0   1000012332_3700058682   NaN 1   0   0   0   0
1   1000012332_3700058682   NaN 0   0   0   0   0
2   1000025219_4231004519   NaN 1   0   0   0   0
3   1000025219_4231004519   NaN 1   0   0   0   0
4   1000036902_602553643    NaN 1   0   0   0   0
```

Can someone shed some light on why the column 'Visitor_ID' would not group together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should probably use something on which it should group by

you can use

```
df.groupby(['Visitor_ID']).sum()

OR

df.groupby(['Visitor_ID']).mean()
```

like this, you have to specify what operation you want to be performed on the group